# What are the names of these two sci-fi writers?

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for the names (which I have forgotten) of two authors who co-author sci-fi novels.
Both authors are actual scientists and they use their specialized knowledge to lend authenticity to the stories. I have read two novels they co-authored both in the past two years: one centered on a Nazi weapons research base in the South American rainforest: the other was about an expedition to the Himalayas which discovers a society of Yetis.

Comment: The only recent co-authored book involving Yetis on Amazon is "[The Yeti](https://www.amazon.com/Yeti-Novel-Rick-Chesler-ebook/dp/B01LDJV4CE)" by Rick Chesler and Jack Douglas, from 2016.

Comment: What era?  Within a decade or two.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's possible this is the [*R.J. MacCready*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?12332) series by Bill Schutt (a zoologist) and J.R. Finch.  The first book, [*Hell's Gate*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2267379) (2016), is set in 1944 and involves an Axis plot in central Brazil.  The second book, [*The Himalayan Codex*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2267381) (2017) has the hero in Tibet searching for a new human species that inspired the Yeti myth.

There is a third book in the series, [*The Darwin Strain*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2627368) (2019).

Summary of *Hell's Gate* from [Bill Schutt's site](https://billschutt.com/home-page-content/hells-gate/):

> In 1944, after a three hundred foot Japanese sub is found marooned and deserted, deep in the wilderness of Central Brazil, a team of Army rangers is sent to investigate. But soon they too, are among the missing. Enter Captain R.J. MacCready, a brilliant zoologist who specializes in just this type of mission: in this case to determine why the Japanese are in Brazil and to stop whatever it is they have planned.
>
> After teaming up with his old friend and fellow scientist, Bob Thorne—a man he thought was dead—Mac learns that German and Japanese scientists have actually arrived months earlier on a second sub. After setting up a base camp below the towering cliffs of Brazil’s Central plateau, the Axis forces have set out to construct a weapon that could change the course of WWII. Soon, though, Mac discovers yet another threat – an ancient and deadly species incensed at the arrival of the human invaders and determined to kill anyone they encounter – Axis or Allied.

And the blurb for *The Himalayan Codex* from [the same source](https://billschutt.com/home-page-content/the-himalayan-codex/):

> In the wake of World War II, zoologist and adventurer Captain R. J. MacCready is sent to the frozen mountain valleys of Tibet to find a creature of legend that may hold the secret to humankind’s evolutionary future—or the key to its extinction—in this explosive follow-up to Hell’s Gate.
>
> It is 1946, and the world is beginning to rebuild from the ashes of the devastating war. Marked by the perilous discoveries he encountered in the wilds of Brazil, Captain R. J. MacCready has a new assignment on the other side of the globe—a mission that may help him put the jungle’s horrors behind him. He is headed for the Himalayas, to examine some recently discovered mammoth bones.
>
> Arriving in Asia, Mac knows that the bones are only a cover story. He’s really there to investigate an ancient codex allegedly written by Pliny the Elder, a fascinating text filled with explosive secrets. The Roman naturalist claimed to have discovered a new race of humans, a divergent species that inspired the myth of the Yeti and is rumored to have the ability to accelerate the process of evolution. If Pliny’s assertions are true, this seemingly supernatural ability holds unlimited potential benefits—and unlimited potential for destruction.
>
> Charged with uncovering more about this miracle species, Mac and Yanni set off into the remote mountain valleys of Tibet, using the codex as their guide. But the freezing climate and treacherous terrain are only the beginning of the dangers facing them. They must also contend with the brutal Chinese army and a species of native creature even the Yeti seem to fear. The deeper Mac and Yanni plunge into the unknown, the more certain it appears that they won’t make it out alive.

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem. Now I can finish the trilogy.